# ResourceExhaustedError when building Sequential model

Tags: keras, regression, image-recognition

i have a big problem when trying to build my model,

```
input shape: (1447, 224, 224, 3)
output shape: (1447, 154457)

model = Sequential([
        Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid', input_shape=(224,224,3)),
        BatchNormalization(axis=-1),
        Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid'),
        BatchNormalization(axis=-1),
        Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid'),
        BatchNormalization(axis=-1),
        MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 1)),
        Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid'),
        BatchNormalization(axis=-1),
        MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 1)),
        Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid'),
        BatchNormalization(axis=-1),
        MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 1)),
        Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid'),
        BatchNormalization(axis=-1),
        MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 1)),
        Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid'),
        BatchNormalization(axis=-1),
        Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid', strides=3),
        BatchNormalization(axis=-1),
        Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='valid', strides=3),
        AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(6, 1), strides=1, padding='same'),
        ReLU(),
        BatchNormalization(axis=-1),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(154457, activation='relu'),
        Dense(154457)
    ])
```

i got below error,

```
ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[11264,154457] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:RandomUniform]
```

what is the problem here as i am new to neural network thing.

Comment: This is a memory problem as stated by the error message. You are trying to build a network that is too big. Try a smaller network (ie try a smaller number than 154 457 in the dense layer.)

Comment: thanks for the answer i've chosen 10000 and that was the optimal value for my gpu memory @lcrmorin

Answer (score 1):

As described in the error message, the problem is that your model needs more memory than your GPU has. Note that OOM stands for "out of memory".

The specific layer that is demanding too much memory is `Dense(154457, activation='relu')`. Nevertheless, the last layer is even bigger.

You should think if you really need an output of dimensionality 154457. If you really need it, you maybe should go for approaches that are specifically designed for that scenario, like [adaptive softmax](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04309).

Another option is to use a GPU with more memory that can fit this model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i will try the design when I'm at lab and give my experience

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please consider upvoting it and marking it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Batch size is too big - 1447. Try a small one like 4 and then increase it until you get OOM error again.
Batch size always depends on the amount of your free GPU memory.